# Weblogic XA transaction, delayed writing to db even after commit

Tags: jms, weblogic, distributed-transactions, xa

My application uses XA transaction for writing to db and publishing message out on MQ. 
However Consumer application intermittently not able to find data in the database.

We are using
Weblogic 10.3 and oracle 10g

I thought as part of XA transaction, message will be sent out only when db commit is complete.

Any inputs on this will be appreciated..

Thanks.

Comment: Need more info - what errors are you seeing? What is your jdbc setup in weblogic?

Comment: This seems to be related to race condition for XA transactions. Found another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595118/xa-jta-transaction-jms-message-arrives-before-db-changes-are-visible which provides more details.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what data source are you using to execute xa transactions. If it is the emulated one this is expected, as you are only simulating xa.